# Issue when calling a method with return type “void” in same file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3

I am getting an issue when calling a method of return type `-(void)` in same `class`

Issue is:`Instance method - someMethodName not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

Comment: It means that the compiler can't find the method you are trying to call, are you including the proper header(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Declare `someMethodName` in your `.h` file.

Comment: yup..I declared method in .h also.Still I had issue

Comment: can you show your .h file declaration and the code where you are using this method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Xcode can't find a declaration for the method. In most recent version of Xcode you don't need to provide a declaration for a method if the implementation is in the same `.m` that you are calling it from. e.g.:

```
//ExampleClass.m
@implementation ExampleClass
-(void)aMethod {
    [self anotherMethod]; //Xcode can see anotherMethod so doesn't need a declaration.
}

-(void)anotherMethod {
    //...
}
@end
```

However in earlier version of Xcode you would need to provide a declaration. You can do this in the `@interface` in `.h` file:

```
//example.h
@interface ExampleClass : NSObject
-(void)anotherMethod;
@end
```

The problem with putting the declaration in the `.h` is that all other class can see the method, which may cause problems. To get around this you can declare a class continuation within the `.m`:

```
//ExampleClass.m
@interface ExampleClass ()
-(void)anotherMethod;
@end

@implementation ExampleClass
   //...
@end
```